# Operating Overloading in the Scala REPL

Tags: scala, operator-overloading

Probably a very simple answer to this one, but - how do I overload an operator?

The obvious solution seems to be failing, though it's possible I'm misunderstanding what's going wrong:

```
scala> def +(s:Int): Int = {print (s); this + s}
$plus: (s: Int)Int

scala> 1 + 2
res20: Int = 3
```

Naturally I was expecting something like `2res20: Int = 3`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you are trying to do override here, not overloading as Int has already this operator defined.

Comment: What makes you think that the `+` method you've defined corresponds to the method that gets called in `1 + 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, all operators are methods. In order to override an existing method (as `Int` already defines a `+` method), the only way would be to inherit and `override` the `+` method, and then you'd need to operate on the derived type.

As for overloading, you aren't really overloading `Int` when defining a `def +` method in the REPL (quite frankly, I'm quite surprised this method compiles with the use of `this` in the REPL). All you're doing is creating a `+` method which takes a single argument. In order to create a new overload for `Int`, you'll need to use the [pimp my library pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766), or in Scala >= 2.10 via an [implicit class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html):

```
scala> implicit class PimpedInt(x: Int) {
     |   def +(i: Int, s: String): Int = {
     |     println(s)
     |     x + i
     |   }
     | }
defined class PimpedInt

scala> 1 + (1, "hello")
hello
res8: Int = 2
```

Comment: Why not make `PimpedInt` extend `AnyVal`?

Comment: @Jubobs Definitely possible, but wasn't crucial for the example.

Comment: Agreed. I'm surprised `def +(s:Int): Int = {print (s); this + s}` compiles at all, in the REPL. What does `this` refer to, in that case?

Comment: @Jubobs I was surprised as well, it seems that `this.getClass` returns a weird looking type: `res1: type = @4d591d15`. Not sure what REPL magic is happening behind for this to work.

Comment: I would've expected to point to whatever object `+` was called on, whatever it might be. No?

Comment: @linkhyrule5 Not really, since you're defining an *unary* method, there's nothing *binary* about this. The `+` identifier has a special meaning to the Scala compiler.

Comment: Hm? `+` is meant to be a binary operator, though it's defined as a unary method - `3.+(5)` turns into `+(3,5)`, as I understand it.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 What would you expect the compiler to infer the `+` method you've defined as a binary operation? `+(Int, Any)`?

Comment: @Jubobs Is there a reason why it should extend `AnyVal`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz To allow the compiler to micro optimize this operation and avoid allocating an instance of `PimpedInt`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz [Yes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#extension-methods).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `+(Any,Int)`, actually, but yeah, something like that?

Comment: @linkhyrule5 That's not what happens in the REPL or generally when you define a method, sorry to disappoint :). [This is what happens to your method](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a32080397262969bb058197b6cf3f351).

Comment: Hm. Not quite sure what's happening there, I'm afraid - not very familiar with Java bytecode

Comment: It's generally a method called `$plus` which takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`, prints to the console and returns the value. Nothing more.